# How to record system audio on a Mac?

Tags: macos, macos-monterey

I'm using MacOS Monterey in an Imac 2020. I need to record the sound the system is playing at the moment. For instance, if i'm watching a video on Youtube, i want to record the video audio. How can i do it ?

I know how to record using the microphone in Quicktime, but the quality sucks as it will get environment noise too.

I tried the approach Quicktime + Blackhole as described on the link below, but it did not work ; when i try to record with Quicktime selecting the  Blackhole source and playing something on the computer, it won't record anything just silence.

https://blog.accusonus.com/recording-sound-for-video/record-screen-audio/

Comment: *"it did not work"* How did it not work. Tell us precisely what you did & what the results were… because that's about your only freeware option to achieve this, so it's probably worth properly examining before just giving up.

Comment: When i try to record with Quicktime selecting the  Blackhole source and playing something on the computer, it won't record anything just silence.

Comment: Then have a look at [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) or its little brother [Piezo](https://rogueamoeba.com/piezo/)

Comment: @Tetsujin Piezo worked, thanks a lot ! Please put as answer, i'll aceept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't persuade the freeware options to work - Soundflower & the new kid on the block Black Hole, then look to established competitors...

I'm a long-time user of [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) & its little brother [Piezo](https://rogueamoeba.com/piezo/), since they were first forked from the original SoundFlower more than a decade ago.

They're not free, but have been solid and are updated frequently.

Comment: Unfortunatelly Black Hole simply does not work for me. Piezo worked at first, i'll buy a license, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Recently also wanted to record system audio on my Mac.
It seems to be possible now (= beginning with macOS 13 Ventura) to record system audio *without* installing any kernel extensions or audio server plug-ins. At least I found this utility which is distributed via MAS and doesn't seem to install any additional stuff: https://www.peakstep.com/news/2023/06/claquette-system-audio-recording.html

Sadly the built-in screen recording utility of macOS doesn't support this yet. Let's hope the next macOS version will integrate that.

Comment: As of 2023/07/10 the link provided leads to a 404 page on an nginx server :(

Comment: Works for me (2023/07/11) - Maybe a site/hosting hiccup.